# How to check for internet availability in c++

Tags: c++, c, wininet

I wrote one small function to check internet connection availability

```
void cis()
{
    if(InternetCheckConnection(NULL,FLAG_ICC_FORCE_CONNECTION,0))
    {
        cout << "internet alive";
    }
}
```

I'm using `WinInet.h` for `InternetCheckConnection()`. Now the problem is that I get the following linker error:

```
[Linker error] undefined reference to `_imp__InternetCheckConnectionA@12'
```

I am using DevC++ for my project. Any ideas on how to fix this linker problem or any other ideas to check for an active internet connection?

Comment: You probably need to link some library.

Comment: Did you check the [documentation[)http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384346%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the function you're calling?  The "requirements" section lists this little piece of information: `Library: Wininet.lib`. By the way, congratulations on having found the single worst, buggiest and most outdated IDE possible. How is it even *possible* to end up using Dev-C++? That thing is *ancient* and even when it wasn't, it *sucked*

Comment: Please excuse, but your posting is a mess. Even if you are not a native english speaker it should at least be possible to format your source properly, to start sentences with capitals and to finish them using a full-stop.

Comment: See if you add reference to WinInet.dll

Comment: @jalf i used overall dev c++ , its now updated .... also anyother good IDE u wana suggest :) but do not suggest microsfot studio :D

Comment: @darkworks there are express versions of Visual Studio which are very powerful. Would you mind giving the reason why you don't want to use that?

Comment: @jalf i have problems with compiling , linking like that with microsoft products ,

Comment: @jalf well lets try , i have visual stduio 2012 , let see what happen when i copy my code to it

Comment: @jalf well i created console application project in visual studio under vc++ tab i press run button it gives error on its pre added coded that  fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'SDKDDKVer.h': No such file or directory    i have not added code yet its pre coded when creating project

Comment: @jalf i have visual studio 2012 ultimate edition , so tell na how to fix this SDKDDVer.h  problem

Comment: @darkworks which project type did you create? Make sure to select Win32 Console Application, and then from the Wizard that pops up, select `Empty project` to get rid of all the Microsoft cruft. Yes, Visual Studio has horrible project defaults.

Comment: @jalf ok tell one thing more where can i did my libraries i mean .h file in dev c we place in /include folder  , also libs in /libs folder so what about libs in visual studio too

Comment: I don't understand the question. Where can you *what* with libraries? Where you can find them? Where you should place them? Something else?

Comment: @jalf  ya  i want to know in visual studio how can we add libraires (.h files) and libs (.a files )  i mean their folders location where they can be placed , in dev c++ normally the paths for header files are /include folder and for lib ./libs

Comment: @darkworks: you can place them wherever you like, but this one is already available with the Windows SDK (and, as far as I know, also with VS Express). Just open project properties and specify the library under linker inputs

Comment: `#pragma comment(lib, "wininet.lib")` and `if (!InternetCheckConnectionW(L"http://google.com", FLAG_ICC_FORCE_CONNECTION, 0))` this good works )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a linker error. as per the documentation you need to use `wininet` library. adding `-lwininet` in makefile may work.

Comment: @darkworks: You can mark an answer as accepted b clicking the white checkmark on the left.

Comment: ya i will accept but say wait .... minutes :D

Comment: The reason for that forced wait is that you often get multiple answers if you wait a bit, and then you can accept the best of them. Whereas if you accept an answer immediately, that typically discourages others from answering, so you might get poorer answers overall.

Comment: where to add -lwininet option in Visual Studio 2013?

Answer (score 2):

For unix

```
    if (system("ping www.google.com -c 2 > /dev/nul") == 0) {
    cout << "all good" << endl;
}else{
    cout << "bad" << endl;
}
```

Windows

```
    if (system("ping www.google.com -t 2 > nul") == 0) {
    cout << "all good" << endl;
}else{
    cout << "bad" << endl;
}
```

Comment: ya but some isp have blocked ping commmand , like in school u cant ping google.com

Comment: True; it's good you found a solution thou!

Answer (score 0):

It found your header, however you need to link to the libraries.  Try adding Wininet.lib to your project(try as a file or in the linker properties) and make sure that the Windows SDK is properly installed on your system.